# Loadrunner controller assigning different jobs to Vusers

Tags: loadrunner

I have one scenario where I recorded the script 
-login - many barcodes and click on one barcode and enter value . log out 
My question is in controller if I am running 10 Vusers then can I assign each vuser one each barcode and if yes how I can do that.
This is my first post here .
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Parameterization.

Covered in training, covered in online tutorial, covered in parameterization section of VUGEN guide.

Comment: Can I have the link for training and tutorial for parameterization. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I have the link for training and tutorial for parameterization. I am using Truclient to record the script. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be asked to perform without training in this field - Your management is not interested in your or your project success.  Tutorial is available for download from the same site as the community edition.  The manuals which include parameterization information are included with your local installation.